# Can web servers track new GCP VMs (or GCP instances)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Question is:

In GCP (Google Cloud Platform), I am trying to figure out if each time I create a new instance from the same snapshot, would a website who is using browser fingerprinting see my snapshot as the same computer, or as a new computer? And if the answer would be the former, then how could I get the result to be the latter, because I want each instance created from the same snapshot to be seen as a new computer?

Comment: My loose thinking is that a web server exposed from the cloud appears to a browser as the set of HTTP responses coming back from an HTTP request.  What are you thinking would be in that response that would differ from one instance of a server to another?   Surely the nature of cloud is that we no longer care about the infrastructure that serves up a request as more or less instances can be spun up/down as needed?

Comment: Could you also consider changing the subject/title of the question.  It feels too vague to be a good title.

Comment: I’m using a Windows 2016 desktop virtual machine, which I use on other sites in this case. So I set things up the way I want and made a snapshot. So when I create other instances off of that snapshot, I don’t want those instances to be viewed as coming from the same virtual machine, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the specific fingerprint the website is getting and what your definition of a "new computer" is :

- Properties related to the softwares (like browser version, number of plugins installed, ...) should be the same as they are restored from the snapshot
- Properties related to the hardware can be different if the new instance uses a different configuration and so a distinction can be made.
- Properties related to the public IP (for what I think of, it is not really fingerprinting as it is not related to a specific machine, but whatever) can also serve as a distinction property. But two distinct IP addresses can be two distinct computers or one computer that changed network.

I never used GCP, so I don't know if new public IP addresses are allocated on new instances starts. But even if they don't use the IP address in the fingerprint, you can dynamically change some of your browser properties with a plugin or something...